# Curve_fit not giving parameters to fit data correctly

Tags: python, scipy

I have data sets called `E` and `V`, and a function. This function takes V and 4 parameters as an input. Parameters `E0` and `V0` should be the minimum values of the function.

For curve fitting, I gave some initial values for the parameters. `E0` and `V0` are given as the minimum values of corresponding data sets. The theoretical value of `B0` should be 28 so I gave it that and I give a random value for `B1`.

After the curve fitting, I try to get the minimum of the function and find `E0` and `V0`. The values I get seem to be okay. Then I plot my data and the defined function. The curve_fit results do not match with my data. I think the problem is in the fitting part but I am not sure. `E` and `V` are my experimental results and I know there is nothing with them.

Here is the code:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

V = np.array([9359.78033951, 10835.11571553, 12457.86763189, 14235.05592385, 16173.70042667, 18280.82097561, 20563.43740591, 23028.56955282, 25683.23725162, 28534.46033754, 31589.25864585])

E = np.array([12.73271364, 10.56261464, 8.21189843, 5.67853559, 3.18963332, 1.76136256,2.35816986,  5.01274293,  9.64990078, 16.22373202, 24.7102355])

E0 = min(E)
V0 = min(V)
print(V0,E0)

def func(V, E0, V0, B0, B1):
         return E0 + B0*V/B1 * (((V0/V)**B1)/(B1-1) + 1);

p0 = [E0, V0, 28, 100]    
params, param2 = curve_fit(func, V, E, p0)

V0_new = fmin(func, V0, args=(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]))
E0_new = func(V, params[0], V0_new, params[2], params[3])

for ii in range(len(V)):
plt.plot(V, E, '-k')
plt.plot(V[ii], func(V[ii], params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]), 'or')
```

After some runs I started getting this error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-ec759702af45> in <module>
      6 
      7 p0 = [E0, V0, 28, 100]
----> 8 params, param2 = curve_fit(func, V, E, p0)
      9 
     10 V0_new = fmin(func, V0, args=(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]))

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    753         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)
    754         if ier not in [1, 2, 3, 4]:
--> 755             raise RuntimeError("Optimal parameters not found: " + errmsg)
    756     else:
    757         # Rename maxfev (leastsq) to max_nfev (least_squares), if specified.

RuntimeError: Optimal parameters not found: Number of calls to function has reached maxfev = 1000.
```

And now I don't even get the values after optimization. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit** I somehow managed to get the figure again. You see the points don't fit the data.

[fig.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmhL7.png)

**Edit2** I keep running the script and sometimes I get this error and it won't give me any parameters...

`Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.`

So what I need is to fix this maximum evaluation problem, then find a way to get correct parameters that fit the data properly.

Comment: I still have the same problems when I change the data set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mathematical operations underlying in `curve_fit` are better to be conducted on numpy arrays instead of regular list. Change first few lines of your code to:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import numpy as np

V = np.array([9359.78033951, 10835.11571553, 12457.86763189, 14235.05592385, 16173.70042667, 18280.82097561, 20563.43740591, 23028.56955282, 25683.23725162, 28534.46033754, 31589.25864585])

E = np.array([12.73271364, 10.56261464, 8.21189843, 5.67853559, 3.18963332, 1.76136256,2.35816986,  5.01274293,  9.64990078, 16.22373202, 24.7102355])
```

The error you get is a result of a chain of function calls `fsolve` -> `_root_hybr`, which then calls fortran minipack routine where loop reaches maximum number.

I tried to recreate your error, but what I get is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-134dfaf77356> in <module>
     18 
     19 V0_new = fmin(func, V0, args=(params[0], params[1], params[2], params[3]))
---> 20 E0_new = func(V, params[0], V0_new, params[2], params[3])

<ipython-input-1-134dfaf77356> in func(V, E0, V0, B0, B1)
     12 
     13 def func(V, E0, V0, B0, B1):
---> 14          return E0 + B0*V/B1 * (((V0/V)**B1)/(B1-1) + 1);
     15 
     16 p0 = [E0, V0, 28, 100]

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'
```

This error is not present when you change arrays to np.array.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was actually getting the data from a txt file and I just pasted the data here like that, my bad... I will correct what you said but unfortunately that is not the source of the error. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sure. I just thought that the root cause might be the same but the error manifests differently depending on system/package version etc. Do you use `loadtxt` from numpy to generate input?

Comment: I use genfromtxt, but I just edited the question and now the only problem is that results I get from curve_fitting do not fit my data.

Comment: Note that covariance array (param2) elements are all inf. You started with too extreme values of B0 and B1 and the algorithm could not find the solution. change:


   p0 = [E0, V0, -1, -1]

and it works

Comment: I tried what you said and now I get the error `Warning: Maximum number of function evaluations has been exceeded.` for curve_fit. I don't understand why it does that. I even restarted the kernel but nothing changed.

Comment: Also I know B0 is 28, shouldn't I keep at like that?

Comment: `curve_fit` gave me values:
E0, V0, B0, B1 = 4.37e+01,  1.87e+04,  4.87e-03, -1.215e+00

Comment: Can you fit them to the data? How does it look?

Comment: Okay I just used your parameters. It works perfectly thank you. But I still cannot get those values.